# Mount options for BTRFS on an external USB drive

Tags: btrfs

I've formatted my external HD with BTRFS (aware of the risks). What are options I should use to increase failure tolerance on sudden power loss to the drive?

Comment: FYI: [Fujitsu tested 1,000 power loss scenarios on btrfs and no corruption occurred](http://events.linuxfoundation.jp/sites/events/files/slides/linux_file_system_analysis_for_IVI_systems.pdf). I'd still like to enable any options which improve my chances.

Comment: Mind linking to the risks? I was thinking of making the jump to btrfs myself for my externals but I find little current information of risks (other than its only recently been dubbed stable)

Comment: Just search the internet for people who got screwed with BTRFS: http://bit.ly/1CpyLCn

Answer (score 6, accepted):

main danger if you would use mounting option "notreelog" which must be avoided in case of external drive. Also using of old Kernel versions increase the risk.

Other significant option for performance and also data safety is:

> commit=number (since 3.12)
>   Set the interval of periodic commit, 30 seconds by default.

So to sacrifice performance but increase safety use
"commit=1" in mounting options.

Also I usually add "noatime" if there is no need for such information, which removes unnecessary write operations on file access (read), thus reducing risk.

One more good option is "recovery", which enables automatic recovery in case drive WAS unplugged or just lost the power, or since 4.6, "usebackuproot" which has replaced "recovery".

Comment: Yeah, `commit` stuck out when reading the filesystem info. `noatime` is also good to know, but this is the first time I'm hearing about `recovery`.